# Datastage: Looping with multiple values

Tags: datastage

I have multiple Date and Store values in an excel, I need to loop the datastage parallel job based on Date and Store. Parallel job has SQL query based on Date and Store so i need to pass these values from Sequence job.

I developed a Sequence job with looping condition but i was able to loop only with 1 column(Either Date or Store). Is there anyway i can pass both Date and store to the parallel job?

I clubbed both Date and store into a single column and try to pass to the parallel job but i am not able to split the parameter value and run the SQL query.

Is there any suggestions on this please?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you 'clubbed' your values by concatenating them with a split character of your choice. In the sequence job, use a User Variable Stage in the loop (between the start-loop stage and your parallel job) to split the pair into two variables e.g. by using the [field function](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=functions-field-function). You can then pass them as two seperate params to the parallel job.